# Angular 2 declaring dynamic property inside component

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I want to declare some properties inside the component like so

```
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {

    hero1:
    hero2:
    hero3:
    hero4:
    ...
    hero999:

}
```

Is there a better way to declare these properties instead of writing them all out?

Comment: You can use a single array property to hold all values.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: you can also create new class to hold all property's and use that class by initializing new instance

Comment: is it possible to create them dynamically using loops?

Comment: You could use `this['hero' + counter++] = null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: any[] = [];

  constructor() {
    for(var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
      this.heroes.push('hero'+i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: getting error `caused by: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` and then when I change `hero:hero[];` to `hero:hero[]=[];` I get error `caused by: Hero is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, right, forgot initialization `= []`. I don't know what you want to store in the array. I assume instances of `Hero` for this a `class Hero{}` needs to exist and be imported. If it doesn't you get this error.

Comment: was looking for something like `this.hero.push('hero'+i);`

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to write properties is to take advantage of typescript interfaces.
You can define the options that are permitted in the interface and use it similar to this:

```js
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
    private options: Options

    constructor() {
      this.options = {
        option1 : 'val1',
        option3 : [1,2]

      }
    }

}

export interface Options {
  option1: string,
  option2?: boolean,
  option3: number[]
}
```